# Find out frequency of certain integers appearing in an array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

Say I have two arrays. One array A of a set of integers - all distinct. Another array B of a list of integers, all appearing in array A, but not necessarily distinct. For example:

A could be Array(123, 456, 789)
B could be Array(123, 123, 456, 123, 789, 456)

I want to create an array C, which tells us the frequency of each element (from array A) appearing in array B. In this case, C would be Array(3, 2, 1) because 123 appears 3 times, 456 appears 2 times, and 789 appears 1 time.

What is an efficient way to do this in Scala?

My attempt is

```
val C: Array[Int] = Array.fill(3)(0)
var idx = 0

for(i <- A){for(j <- B){if(j == i){C(idx) += 1}}
idx += 1}

for(i <- C){println(i)}
```

But I understand that this is probably inefficient, and would take a long time if I am dealing with a much larger array A and array B. But I am restricted to for loops and if statements since I am only a beginner with Scala. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient? The problem is by definition **O(n)**, your solution is actually the most efficient way to do it _(well, you may replace the `foreach` with a `while`)_ - However, your solution is not idiomatic, there are more decorative ways to solve the problem, although they won't be that efficient.

Comment: Actually the solution has `O(A.length * B.length)` complexity

Comment: [This](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/fjjMKaVYQdiltdgMFH17Dg/1) would be the idiomatic way to solve the problem, no mutability, no use of plain `Arrays` but rather using real collections like `List` or `ÀrraySeq`, and trying to be declarative. More over, I would not return another `ArraySeq` containing the count, but I would just return the `Map[A, Int]` itself. -- On second thought, I believe this solution is even faster than yours since this avoids the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that `n` is length of Array `A` and `m` is length of array `B`.

As of now your solution is `O(n * m)`

You can improve this to `O(n + m)` by using a `mutable HashMap` and `O(n)` extra space.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val a = Array(123, 456, 789)
val b = Array(123, 123, 456, 123, 789, 456)

val countMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, Int]

// add all integers in `a` with count 0
for (i <- a) {
  countMap.put(i, 0)
}

// iterate on b
// and update the count in countMap (if exists)
for (i <- b) {
  countMap.get(i).foreach(c => countMap.put(i, c + 1))
}

// fill your array `c`
val c = Array.ofDim[Int](a.length)

for ((i, index) <- a.zipWithIndex) {
  c(index) = countMap.getOrElse(i, 0)
}

println(c.mkString(", "))
// 3, 2, 1
```

Keep in mind that `for's` for Scala collections have their own costs, you can improve it further by using while loops.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

val a = Array(123, 456, 789)
val b = Array(123, 123, 456, 123, 789, 456)

val countMap = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, Int]

// to use with our while loops
var i = 0

// add all integers in `a` with count 0
i = 0
while (i < a.length) {
  countMap.put(a(i), 0)
  i = i + 1
}

// iterate on b
// and update the count in countMap (if exists)
i = 0
while (i < b.length) {
  if (countMap.contains(b(i))) {
    countMap.put(b(i), countMap(b(i)) + 1)
  }
  i = i + 1
}

// fill your array `c`
val c = Array.ofDim[Int](a.length)

i = 0
while (i < a.length) {
  c(i) = countMap.getOrElse(a(i), 0)
  i = i + 1
}

println(c.mkString(", "))
// 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Since we are going the full imperative route for raw performance, I wonder if there is a better alternative than a `HashMap` to avoid boxing, I can see [`IntMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/IntMap.html) but the comment says that it is superseded by `HasMap` - Anyways, `groupMapReduce` should be pretty fast nevertheless.